# Spring Security protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) Please explain the proper use of " and() ". What does it mean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have lots and lots of examples from  many search results in this platform and others, but I can't find an explanation of the " and() ". Obviously some kind of delimiter.  Possibly doing the logical AND (&&) but maybe not.

I want to understand proper usage and what it does...what it means.

I hope this question is salient and the answers useful for others

Reference:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html#configure-org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity-

Then inside of that document:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)
                  throws java.lang.Exception
```

Override this method to configure the HttpSecurity. Typically subclasses should not invoke this method by calling super as it may override their configuration. The default configuration is:

```
http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().and().httpBasic();
```

Comment: the `and()` just returns de securityBuilder for method chaining

Comment: `and()` is essentially a human-friendly way of saying "end this section and go back to the main configuration context".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Lets take the following example. Both are equivalent.

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll();

        http.logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
```

```
     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
```

- Actually we are configuring different configurers here like `ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer`, `FormLoginConfigurer` and `LogoutConfigurer` in this example. Even though, they are configured separately in the first one, they are all applied together. So here `AND` plays **the logical AND role**.
- Now notice, for example,  return type of`.anyRequest().authenticated()` is `ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry`, but the method `formLogin()` is only present in object of type `HttpSecurity`, so in builder pattern `and()` **plays the second role of switching return type**, i.e as soon as you call, `anyRequest().authenticated().and()`, the return type is `HttpSecurity` so now it allows you start `formLogin()`
- See the `Intellij` showing the return types at various points.

  [image]

Comment: Your explanation is very clear - thank you for this.